# ParallelTry Hangs on previously working code

Tags: functions, parallelization, broken-code

When I run the below `ParallelTry` command, it just sits on it and says its being evaluated, but I cant abort it, it doesn't return what I am expecting, and I have to quit the kernel to stop the evaluation. Heres the MWE of my code:

```
LaunchKernels[$ProcessorCount]
kernels = ParallelTable[$KernelID -> i, {i, $KernelCount}];
CurrentStep = ConstantArray[0, $KernelCount];
SetSharedVariable[kernels, CurrentStep];
PrintTemporary@Dynamic[CurrentStep // Column];
(*Run the parallelized search routine*)
ParallelizedResult = 
    ParallelTry[
  (CurrentStep[[$KernelID /. kernels]] = 
     "Kernel " <> ToString[$KernelID] <> " executing chunk " <> 
      ToString[#];
    #) &,
        {{1, 1000}, {1001, 2000}, {2001, 3000}, {3001, 4000}, {4001, 
    5000}, {5001, 6000}, {6001, 7000}}]
```

I would expect this to briefly say (for example)

```
Kernel 6 executing chunk {1, 1000}
Kernel 5 executing chunk {1001, 2000}
Kernel 4 executing chunk {2001, 3000}
Kernel 3 executing chunk {3001, 4000}
Kernel 2 executing chunk {4001, 5000}
Kernel 1 executing chunk {5001, 6000}
```

followed by
`{1, 1000}`
replacing the above print. It should complete the evaluation in only a split second. However, it just hangs on the first temporary print statement and doesn't allow me to abort the evaluation. I've narrowed it down to the

`CurrentStep[[$KernelID/.kernels]]=`

step. Removing this fixes it, but I don't know why this section is causing the unexpected behavior.

This code has worked before so I don't know why upgrading to 12.1 broke it. Could it be a bug in 12.1?
Any help is appreciated!

Update

It appears that this code hangs when the number of slave kernels is less than 7 and executes as expected when the number is 7 or more (see comments). Possible 12.1 bug?

Comment: Very strange. When I set `LaunchKernels` by hand to the maximal number of kernels: `LaunchKernels[8]`  in my case, I get  a  result rather fast. But when I use `LaunchKernels[$ProcessorCount]` I get our problem ($ProcessorCount is 4)

Comment: @Daniel Huber does the same problem occur when you use `LaunchKernels[4]`?

Comment: Yes, with `LaunchKernels[4]` it does occur.

Comment: Yes, that is strange. I've noticed that if I launch 7 or more slave kernels, then the code behaves as expected. But if I launch 6 or less (```$ProcessorCount``` = 6 for me), then it hangs.